# Invariant principle in tranformation number

Tags: combinatorics, invariance

In a pentagon, each vertex is assigned a real number which sum is positive. If there is a negative number $y$, use the transformation $$T:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x+y,-y,y+z)$$ where $x,y,$ and $z$ are consecutive vertices. This transformation can always used whenever there still exist a negative real number. Is it necessary after a number of transformation, all number in the pentagon will be non negative?

Comment: not sure. What happens for a triangle?

Comment: This is like spreading peaks; you could try to show that the non-constant Fourier modes or the sum of squares or some other measure of deviation from the mean is reduced to a point that's incomatible with negative values.

Comment: And what is the specific measure? I already tried but couldn’t find the right one :(

Comment: @joriki your argument with sum of squares works for a triangle and vertex numbers integers. If the label $y$ is negative (but $x+y+z >0$) then flipping at $y$ strictly decreases the value of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2.$  Therefore works for rational labels, and there is probably a density argument for reals. Not sure how well this works for integer vertex labels in a square or pentagon

Comment: @joriki don't know whether you retain any interest, it appears that a greedy algorithm based on sum of squares works; the unusual aspect is that, for the pentagon, it appears that it may take up to five steps to get a decrease in SOS. As I am using all integers, I have not included the mean value in the sum of squares calculation. Not important as long as I stick to vertex sum equal to $1.$

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a greedy algorithm for a square. It looks at the negative entries that can be flipped, and uses the one the minimizes the sum of all four squares. In contrast with the triangle, the SOS occasionally increases, so this does not directly lead to a proof.

Interesting: with four vertices, it appears that one of the next three steps  has a strictly smaller sum of squares. If true, that sort of thing **does** lead to a proof, for the case of four vertices.

```
Tue Jun 26 10:55:39 PDT 2018
  -1  -2  -3   7
           * 
  -1  -5   3   4    step 1     sos 51
   * 
   1  -6   3   3    step 2     sos 55
       * 
  -5   6  -3   3    step 3     sos 79
   * 
   5   1  -3  -2    step 4     sos 39
               * 
   3   1  -5   2    step 5     sos 39
           * 
   3  -4   5  -3    step 6     sos 59
       * 
  -1   4   1  -3    step 7     sos 27
   * 
   1   3   1  -4    step 8     sos 27
               * 
  -3   3  -3   4    step 9     sos 43
   * 
   3   0  -3   1    step 10     sos 19
           * 
   3  -3   3  -2    step 11     sos 31
       * 
   0   3   0  -2    step 12     sos 13
               * 
  -2   3  -2   2    step 13     sos 21
   * 
   2   1  -2   0    step 14     sos 9
           * 
   2  -1   2  -2    step 15     sos 13
               * 
   0  -1   0   2    step 16     sos 5
       * 
  -1   1  -1   2    step 17     sos 7
   * 
   1   0  -1   1    step 18     sos 3
           * 
   1  -1   1   0    step 19     sos 3
       * 
   0   1   0   0    step 20     sos 1
Tue Jun 26 10:55:39 PDT 2018
```

=======================================================================

Here is one with larger numbers. As you can see, sometimes the sos increases for a few steps before shrinking again.

```
Tue Jun 26 11:17:07 PDT 2018
  -1   4 -31  29
           * 
  -1 -27  31  -2    step 1     sos 1695
       * 
 -28  27   4  -2    step 2     sos 1533
               * 
 -30  27   2   2    step 3     sos 1637
   * 
  30  -3   2 -28    step 4     sos 1697
               * 
   2  -3 -26  28    step 5     sos 1473
           * 
   2 -29  26   2    step 6     sos 1525
       * 
 -27  29  -3   2    step 7     sos 1583
   * 
  27   2  -3 -25    step 8     sos 1367
               * 
   2   2 -28  25    step 9     sos 1417
           * 
   2 -26  28  -3    step 10     sos 1473
       * 
 -24  26   2  -3    step 11     sos 1265
   * 
  24   2   2 -27    step 12     sos 1313
               * 
  -3   2 -25  27    step 13     sos 1367
           * 
  -3 -23  25   2    step 14     sos 1167
       * 
 -26  23   2   2    step 15     sos 1213
   * 
  26  -3   2 -24    step 16     sos 1265
               * 
   2  -3 -22  24    step 17     sos 1073
           * 
   2 -25  22   2    step 18     sos 1117
       * 
 -23  25  -3   2    step 19     sos 1167
   * 
  23   2  -3 -21    step 20     sos 983
               * 
   2   2 -24  21    step 21     sos 1025
           * 
   2 -22  24  -3    step 22     sos 1073
       * 
 -20  22   2  -3    step 23     sos 897
   * 
  20   2   2 -23    step 24     sos 937
               * 
  -3   2 -21  23    step 25     sos 983
           * 
  -3 -19  21   2    step 26     sos 815
       * 
 -22  19   2   2    step 27     sos 853
   * 
  22  -3   2 -20    step 28     sos 897
               * 
   2  -3 -18  20    step 29     sos 737
           * 
   2 -21  18   2    step 30     sos 773
       * 
 -19  21  -3   2    step 31     sos 815
   * 
  19   2  -3 -17    step 32     sos 663
               * 
   2   2 -20  17    step 33     sos 697
           * 
   2 -18  20  -3    step 34     sos 737
       * 
 -16  18   2  -3    step 35     sos 593
   * 
  16   2   2 -19    step 36     sos 625
               * 
  -3   2 -17  19    step 37     sos 663
           * 
  -3 -15  17   2    step 38     sos 527
       * 
 -18  15   2   2    step 39     sos 557
   * 
  18  -3   2 -16    step 40     sos 593
               * 
   2  -3 -14  16    step 41     sos 465
           * 
   2 -17  14   2    step 42     sos 493
       * 
 -15  17  -3   2    step 43     sos 527
   * 
  15   2  -3 -13    step 44     sos 407
               * 
   2   2 -16  13    step 45     sos 433
           * 
   2 -14  16  -3    step 46     sos 465
       * 
 -12  14   2  -3    step 47     sos 353
   * 
  12   2   2 -15    step 48     sos 377
               * 
  -3   2 -13  15    step 49     sos 407
           * 
  -3 -11  13   2    step 50     sos 303
       * 
 -14  11   2   2    step 51     sos 325
   * 
  14  -3   2 -12    step 52     sos 353
               * 
   2  -3 -10  12    step 53     sos 257
           * 
   2 -13  10   2    step 54     sos 277
       * 
 -11  13  -3   2    step 55     sos 303
   * 
  11   2  -3  -9    step 56     sos 215
               * 
   2   2 -12   9    step 57     sos 233
           * 
   2 -10  12  -3    step 58     sos 257
       * 
  -8  10   2  -3    step 59     sos 177
   * 
   8   2   2 -11    step 60     sos 193
               * 
  -3   2  -9  11    step 61     sos 215
           * 
  -3  -7   9   2    step 62     sos 143
       * 
 -10   7   2   2    step 63     sos 157
   * 
  10  -3   2  -8    step 64     sos 177
               * 
   2  -3  -6   8    step 65     sos 113
           * 
   2  -9   6   2    step 66     sos 125
       * 
  -7   9  -3   2    step 67     sos 143
   * 
   7   2  -3  -5    step 68     sos 87
               * 
   2   2  -8   5    step 69     sos 97
           * 
   2  -6   8  -3    step 70     sos 113
       * 
  -4   6   2  -3    step 71     sos 65
   * 
   4   2   2  -7    step 72     sos 73
               * 
  -3   2  -5   7    step 73     sos 87
           * 
  -3  -3   5   2    step 74     sos 47
       * 
  -6   3   2   2    step 75     sos 53
   * 
   6  -3   2  -4    step 76     sos 65
               * 
   2  -3  -2   4    step 77     sos 33
           * 
   2  -5   2   2    step 78     sos 37
       * 
  -3   5  -3   2    step 79     sos 47
   * 
   3   2  -3  -1    step 80     sos 23
               * 
   2   2  -4   1    step 81     sos 25
           * 
   2  -2   4  -3    step 82     sos 33
               * 
  -1  -2   1   3    step 83     sos 15
   * 
   1  -3   1   2    step 84     sos 15
       * 
  -2   3  -2   2    step 85     sos 21
   * 
   2   1  -2   0    step 86     sos 9
           * 
   2  -1   2  -2    step 87     sos 13
               * 
   0  -1   0   2    step 88     sos 5
       * 
  -1   1  -1   2    step 89     sos 7
   * 
   1   0  -1   1    step 90     sos 3
           * 
   1  -1   1   0    step 91     sos 3
       * 
   0   1   0   0    step 92     sos 1
Tue Jun 26 11:17:07 PDT 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

greedy algorithm for pentagon. It does appear that the sum of squares may grow, but always shrinks from its current size within five steps. If true, that is a proof.

```
Tue Jun 26 12:07:21 PDT 2018
 -77  44 -31  28  37  sos  10979
           * 
 -77  13  31  -3  37    step 1     sos 8437
               * 
 -77  13  28   3  34    step 2     sos 8047
   * 
  77 -64  28   3 -43    step 3     sos 12667
       * 
  13  64 -36   3 -43    step 4     sos 7419
           * 
  13  28  36 -33 -43    step 5     sos 5187
               * 
  13  28   3  33 -76    step 6     sos 7827
                   * 
 -63  28   3 -43  76    step 7     sos 12387
   * 
  63 -35   3 -43  13    step 8     sos 7221
       * 
  28  35 -32 -43  13    step 9     sos 5051
           * 
  28   3  32 -75  13    step 10     sos 7611
               * 
  28   3 -43  75 -62    step 11     sos 12111
                   * 
 -34   3 -43  13  62    step 12     sos 7027
   * 
  34 -31 -43  13  28    step 13     sos 4919
       * 
   3  31 -74  13  28    step 14     sos 7399
           * 
   3 -43  74 -61  28    step 15     sos 11839
               * 
   3 -43  13  61 -33    step 16     sos 6837
                   * 
 -30 -43  13  28  33    step 17     sos 4791
   * 
  30 -73  13  28   3    step 18     sos 7191
       * 
 -43  73 -60  28   3    step 19     sos 11571
           * 
 -43  13  60 -32   3    step 20     sos 6651
               * 
 -43  13  28  32 -29    step 21     sos 4667
                   * 
 -72  13  28   3  29    step 22     sos 6987
   * 
  72 -59  28   3 -43    step 23     sos 11307
       * 
  13  59 -31   3 -43    step 24     sos 6469
           * 
  13  28  31 -28 -43    step 25     sos 4547
               * 
  13  28   3  28 -71    step 26     sos 6787
                   * 
 -58  28   3 -43  71    step 27     sos 11047
   * 
  58 -30   3 -43  13    step 28     sos 6291
       * 
  28  30 -27 -43  13    step 29     sos 4431
           * 
  28   3  27 -70  13    step 30     sos 6591
               * 
  28   3 -43  70 -57    step 31     sos 10791
                   * 
 -29   3 -43  13  57    step 32     sos 6117
   * 
  29 -26 -43  13  28    step 33     sos 4319
       * 
   3  26 -69  13  28    step 34     sos 6399
           * 
   3 -43  69 -56  28    step 35     sos 10539
               * 
   3 -43  13  56 -28    step 36     sos 5947
                   * 
 -25 -43  13  28  28    step 37     sos 4211
   * 
  25 -68  13  28   3    step 38     sos 6211
       * 
 -43  68 -55  28   3    step 39     sos 10291
           * 
 -43  13  55 -27   3    step 40     sos 5781
               * 
 -43  13  28  27 -24    step 41     sos 4107
                   * 
 -67  13  28   3  24    step 42     sos 6027
   * 
  67 -54  28   3 -43    step 43     sos 10047
       * 
  13  54 -26   3 -43    step 44     sos 5619
           * 
  13  28  26 -23 -43    step 45     sos 4007
               * 
  13  28   3  23 -66    step 46     sos 5847
                   * 
 -53  28   3 -43  66    step 47     sos 9807
   * 
  53 -25   3 -43  13    step 48     sos 5461
       * 
  28  25 -22 -43  13    step 49     sos 3911
           * 
  28   3  22 -65  13    step 50     sos 5671
               * 
  28   3 -43  65 -52    step 51     sos 9571
                   * 
 -24   3 -43  13  52    step 52     sos 5307
   * 
  24 -21 -43  13  28    step 53     sos 3819
       * 
   3  21 -64  13  28    step 54     sos 5499
           * 
   3 -43  64 -51  28    step 55     sos 9339
               * 
   3 -43  13  51 -23    step 56     sos 5157
                   * 
 -20 -43  13  28  23    step 57     sos 3731
   * 
  20 -63  13  28   3    step 58     sos 5331
       * 
 -43  63 -50  28   3    step 59     sos 9111
           * 
 -43  13  50 -22   3    step 60     sos 5011
               * 
 -43  13  28  22 -19    step 61     sos 3647
                   * 
 -62  13  28   3  19    step 62     sos 5167
   * 
  62 -49  28   3 -43    step 63     sos 8887
       * 
  13  49 -21   3 -43    step 64     sos 4869
           * 
  13  28  21 -18 -43    step 65     sos 3567
               * 
  13  28   3  18 -61    step 66     sos 5007
                   * 
 -48  28   3 -43  61    step 67     sos 8667
   * 
  48 -20   3 -43  13    step 68     sos 4731
       * 
  28  20 -17 -43  13    step 69     sos 3491
           * 
  28   3  17 -60  13    step 70     sos 4851
               * 
  28   3 -43  60 -47    step 71     sos 8451
                   * 
 -19   3 -43  13  47    step 72     sos 4597
   * 
  19 -16 -43  13  28    step 73     sos 3419
       * 
   3  16 -59  13  28    step 74     sos 4699
           * 
   3 -43  59 -46  28    step 75     sos 8239
               * 
   3 -43  13  46 -18    step 76     sos 4467
                   * 
 -15 -43  13  28  18    step 77     sos 3351
   * 
  15 -58  13  28   3    step 78     sos 4551
       * 
 -43  58 -45  28   3    step 79     sos 8031
           * 
 -43  13  45 -17   3    step 80     sos 4341
               * 
 -43  13  28  17 -14    step 81     sos 3287
                   * 
 -57  13  28   3  14    step 82     sos 4407
   * 
  57 -44  28   3 -43    step 83     sos 7827
       * 
  13  44 -16   3 -43    step 84     sos 4219
           * 
  13  28  16 -13 -43    step 85     sos 3227
               * 
  13  28   3  13 -56    step 86     sos 4267
                   * 
 -43  28   3 -43  56    step 87     sos 7627
   * 
  43 -15   3 -43  13    step 88     sos 4101
       * 
  28  15 -12 -43  13    step 89     sos 3171
           * 
  28   3  12 -55  13    step 90     sos 4131
               * 
  28   3 -43  55 -42    step 91     sos 7431
                   * 
 -14   3 -43  13  42    step 92     sos 3987
   * 
  14 -11 -43  13  28    step 93     sos 3119
       * 
   3  11 -54  13  28    step 94     sos 3999
           * 
   3 -43  54 -41  28    step 95     sos 7239
               * 
   3 -43  13  41 -13    step 96     sos 3877
                   * 
 -10 -43  13  28  13    step 97     sos 3071
   * 
  10 -53  13  28   3    step 98     sos 3871
       * 
 -43  53 -40  28   3    step 99     sos 7051
           * 
 -43  13  40 -12   3    step 100     sos 3771
               * 
 -43  13  28  12  -9    step 101     sos 3027
                   * 
 -52  13  28   3   9    step 102     sos 3747
   * 
  52 -39  28   3 -43    step 103     sos 6867
       * 
  13  39 -11   3 -43    step 104     sos 3669
           * 
  13  28  11  -8 -43    step 105     sos 2987
               * 
  13  28   3   8 -51    step 106     sos 3627
                   * 
 -38  28   3 -43  51    step 107     sos 6687
   * 
  38 -10   3 -43  13    step 108     sos 3571
       * 
  28  10  -7 -43  13    step 109     sos 2951
           * 
  28   3   7 -50  13    step 110     sos 3511
               * 
  28   3 -43  50 -37    step 111     sos 6511
                   * 
  -9   3 -43  13  37    step 112     sos 3477
   * 
   9  -6 -43  13  28    step 113     sos 2919
       * 
   3   6 -49  13  28    step 114     sos 3399
           * 
   3 -43  49 -36  28    step 115     sos 6339
               * 
   3 -43  13  36  -8    step 116     sos 3387
                   * 
  -5 -43  13  28   8    step 117     sos 2891
   * 
   5 -48  13  28   3    step 118     sos 3291
       * 
 -43  48 -35  28   3    step 119     sos 6171
           * 
 -43  13  35  -7   3    step 120     sos 3301
               * 
 -43  13  28   7  -4    step 121     sos 2867
                   * 
 -47  13  28   3   4    step 122     sos 3187
   * 
  47 -34  28   3 -43    step 123     sos 6007
       * 
  13  34  -6   3 -43    step 124     sos 3219
           * 
  13  28   6  -3 -43    step 125     sos 2847
               * 
  13  28   3   3 -46    step 126     sos 3087
                   * 
 -33  28   3 -43  46    step 127     sos 5847
   * 
  33  -5   3 -43  13    step 128     sos 3141
       * 
  28   5  -2 -43  13    step 129     sos 2831
           * 
  28   3   2 -45  13    step 130     sos 2991
               * 
  28   3 -43  45 -32    step 131     sos 5691
                   * 
  -4   3 -43  13  32    step 132     sos 3067
   * 
   4  -1 -43  13  28    step 133     sos 2819
       * 
   3   1 -44  13  28    step 134     sos 2899
           * 
   3 -43  44 -31  28    step 135     sos 5539
               * 
   3 -43  13  31  -3    step 136     sos 2997
                   * 
   0 -43  13  28   3    step 137     sos 2811
       * 
 -43  43 -30  28   3    step 138     sos 5391
           * 
 -43  13  30  -2   3    step 139     sos 2931
               * 
 -43  13  28   2   1    step 140     sos 2807
   * 
  43 -30  28   2 -42    step 141     sos 5301
       * 
  13  30  -2   2 -42    step 142     sos 2841
           * 
  13  28   2   0 -42    step 143     sos 2721
                   * 
 -29  28   2 -42  42    step 144     sos 5157
   * 
  29  -1   2 -42  13    step 145     sos 2779
       * 
  28   1   1 -42  13    step 146     sos 2719
               * 
  28   1 -41  42 -29    step 147     sos 5071
                   * 
  -1   1 -41  13  29    step 148     sos 2693
   * 
   1   0 -41  13  28    step 149     sos 2635
           * 
   1 -41  41 -28  28    step 150     sos 4931
               * 
   1 -41  13  28   0    step 151     sos 2635
       * 
 -40  41 -28  28   0    step 152     sos 4849
           * 
 -40  13  28   0   0    step 153     sos 2553
   * 
  40 -27  28   0 -40    step 154     sos 4713
       * 
  13  27   1   0 -40    step 155     sos 2499
                   * 
 -27  27   1 -40  40    step 156     sos 4659
   * 
  27   0   1 -40  13    step 157     sos 2499
               * 
  27   0 -39  40 -27    step 158     sos 4579
                   * 
   0   0 -39  13  27    step 159     sos 2419
           * 
   0 -39  39 -26  27    step 160     sos 4447
               * 
   0 -39  13  26   1    step 161     sos 2367
       * 
 -39  39 -26  26   1    step 162     sos 4395
           * 
 -39  13  26   0   1    step 163     sos 2367
   * 
  39 -26  26   0 -38    step 164     sos 4317
       * 
  13  26   0   0 -38    step 165     sos 2289
                   * 
 -25  26   0 -38  38    step 166     sos 4189
   * 
  25   1   0 -38  13    step 167     sos 2239
               * 
  25   1 -38  38 -25    step 168     sos 4139
                   * 
   0   1 -38  13  25    step 169     sos 2239
           * 
   0 -37  38 -25  25    step 170     sos 4063
               * 
   0 -37  13  25   0    step 171     sos 2163
       * 
 -37  37 -24  25   0    step 172     sos 3939
           * 
 -37  13  24   1   0    step 173     sos 2115
   * 
  37 -24  24   1 -37    step 174     sos 3891
       * 
  13  24   0   1 -37    step 175     sos 2115
                   * 
 -24  24   0 -36  37    step 176     sos 3817
   * 
  24   0   0 -36  13    step 177     sos 2041
               * 
  24   0 -36  36 -23    step 178     sos 3697
                   * 
   1   0 -36  13  23    step 179     sos 1995
           * 
   1 -36  36 -23  23    step 180     sos 3651
               * 
   1 -36  13  23   0    step 181     sos 1995
       * 
 -35  36 -23  23   0    step 182     sos 3579
           * 
 -35  13  23   0   0    step 183     sos 1923
   * 
  35 -22  23   0 -35    step 184     sos 3463
       * 
  13  22   1   0 -35    step 185     sos 1879
                   * 
 -22  22   1 -35  35    step 186     sos 3419
   * 
  22   0   1 -35  13    step 187     sos 1879
               * 
  22   0 -34  35 -22    step 188     sos 3349
                   * 
   0   0 -34  13  22    step 189     sos 1809
           * 
   0 -34  34 -21  22    step 190     sos 3237
               * 
   0 -34  13  21   1    step 191     sos 1767
       * 
 -34  34 -21  21   1    step 192     sos 3195
           * 
 -34  13  21   0   1    step 193     sos 1767
   * 
  34 -21  21   0 -33    step 194     sos 3127
       * 
  13  21   0   0 -33    step 195     sos 1699
                   * 
 -20  21   0 -33  33    step 196     sos 3019
   * 
  20   1   0 -33  13    step 197     sos 1659
               * 
  20   1 -33  33 -20    step 198     sos 2979
                   * 
   0   1 -33  13  20    step 199     sos 1659
           * 
   0 -32  33 -20  20    step 200     sos 2913
               * 
   0 -32  13  20   0    step 201     sos 1593
       * 
 -32  32 -19  20   0    step 202     sos 2809
           * 
 -32  13  19   1   0    step 203     sos 1555
   * 
  32 -19  19   1 -32    step 204     sos 2771
       * 
  13  19   0   1 -32    step 205     sos 1555
                   * 
 -19  19   0 -31  32    step 206     sos 2707
   * 
  19   0   0 -31  13    step 207     sos 1491
               * 
  19   0 -31  31 -18    step 208     sos 2607
                   * 
   1   0 -31  13  18    step 209     sos 1455
           * 
   1 -31  31 -18  18    step 210     sos 2571
               * 
   1 -31  13  18   0    step 211     sos 1455
       * 
 -30  31 -18  18   0    step 212     sos 2509
           * 
 -30  13  18   0   0    step 213     sos 1393
   * 
  30 -17  18   0 -30    step 214     sos 2413
       * 
  13  17   1   0 -30    step 215     sos 1359
                   * 
 -17  17   1 -30  30    step 216     sos 2379
   * 
  17   0   1 -30  13    step 217     sos 1359
               * 
  17   0 -29  30 -17    step 218     sos 2319
                   * 
   0   0 -29  13  17    step 219     sos 1299
           * 
   0 -29  29 -16  17    step 220     sos 2227
               * 
   0 -29  13  16   1    step 221     sos 1267
       * 
 -29  29 -16  16   1    step 222     sos 2195
           * 
 -29  13  16   0   1    step 223     sos 1267
   * 
  29 -16  16   0 -28    step 224     sos 2137
       * 
  13  16   0   0 -28    step 225     sos 1209
                   * 
 -15  16   0 -28  28    step 226     sos 2049
   * 
  15   1   0 -28  13    step 227     sos 1179
               * 
  15   1 -28  28 -15    step 228     sos 2019
                   * 
   0   1 -28  13  15    step 229     sos 1179
           * 
   0 -27  28 -15  15    step 230     sos 1963
               * 
   0 -27  13  15   0    step 231     sos 1123
       * 
 -27  27 -14  15   0    step 232     sos 1879
           * 
 -27  13  14   1   0    step 233     sos 1095
   * 
  27 -14  14   1 -27    step 234     sos 1851
       * 
  13  14   0   1 -27    step 235     sos 1095
                   * 
 -14  14   0 -26  27    step 236     sos 1797
   * 
  14   0   0 -26  13    step 237     sos 1041
               * 
  14   0 -26  26 -13    step 238     sos 1717
                   * 
   1   0 -26  13  13    step 239     sos 1015
           * 
   1 -26  26 -13  13    step 240     sos 1691
               * 
   1 -26  13  13   0    step 241     sos 1015
       * 
 -25  26 -13  13   0    step 242     sos 1639
           * 
 -25  13  13   0   0    step 243     sos 963
   * 
  25 -12  13   0 -25    step 244     sos 1563
       * 
  13  12   1   0 -25    step 245     sos 939
                   * 
 -12  12   1 -25  25    step 246     sos 1539
   * 
  12   0   1 -25  13    step 247     sos 939
               * 
  12   0 -24  25 -12    step 248     sos 1489
                   * 
   0   0 -24  13  12    step 249     sos 889
           * 
   0 -24  24 -11  12    step 250     sos 1417
               * 
   0 -24  13  11   1    step 251     sos 867
       * 
 -24  24 -11  11   1    step 252     sos 1395
           * 
 -24  13  11   0   1    step 253     sos 867
   * 
  24 -11  11   0 -23    step 254     sos 1347
       * 
  13  11   0   0 -23    step 255     sos 819
                   * 
 -10  11   0 -23  23    step 256     sos 1279
   * 
  10   1   0 -23  13    step 257     sos 799
               * 
  10   1 -23  23 -10    step 258     sos 1259
                   * 
   0   1 -23  13  10    step 259     sos 799
           * 
   0 -22  23 -10  10    step 260     sos 1213
               * 
   0 -22  13  10   0    step 261     sos 753
       * 
 -22  22  -9  10   0    step 262     sos 1149
           * 
 -22  13   9   1   0    step 263     sos 735
   * 
  22  -9   9   1 -22    step 264     sos 1131
       * 
  13   9   0   1 -22    step 265     sos 735
                   * 
  -9   9   0 -21  22    step 266     sos 1087
   * 
   9   0   0 -21  13    step 267     sos 691
               * 
   9   0 -21  21  -8    step 268     sos 1027
                   * 
   1   0 -21  13   8    step 269     sos 675
           * 
   1 -21  21  -8   8    step 270     sos 1011
               * 
   1 -21  13   8   0    step 271     sos 675
       * 
 -20  21  -8   8   0    step 272     sos 969
           * 
 -20  13   8   0   0    step 273     sos 633
   * 
  20  -7   8   0 -20    step 274     sos 913
       * 
  13   7   1   0 -20    step 275     sos 619
                   * 
  -7   7   1 -20  20    step 276     sos 899
   * 
   7   0   1 -20  13    step 277     sos 619
               * 
   7   0 -19  20  -7    step 278     sos 859
                   * 
   0   0 -19  13   7    step 279     sos 579
           * 
   0 -19  19  -6   7    step 280     sos 807
               * 
   0 -19  13   6   1    step 281     sos 567
       * 
 -19  19  -6   6   1    step 282     sos 795
           * 
 -19  13   6   0   1    step 283     sos 567
   * 
  19  -6   6   0 -18    step 284     sos 757
       * 
  13   6   0   0 -18    step 285     sos 529
                   * 
  -5   6   0 -18  18    step 286     sos 709
   * 
   5   1   0 -18  13    step 287     sos 519
               * 
   5   1 -18  18  -5    step 288     sos 699
                   * 
   0   1 -18  13   5    step 289     sos 519
           * 
   0 -17  18  -5   5    step 290     sos 663
               * 
   0 -17  13   5   0    step 291     sos 483
       * 
 -17  17  -4   5   0    step 292     sos 619
           * 
 -17  13   4   1   0    step 293     sos 475
   * 
  17  -4   4   1 -17    step 294     sos 611
       * 
  13   4   0   1 -17    step 295     sos 475
                   * 
  -4   4   0 -16  17    step 296     sos 577
   * 
   4   0   0 -16  13    step 297     sos 441
               * 
   4   0 -16  16  -3    step 298     sos 537
                   * 
   1   0 -16  13   3    step 299     sos 435
           * 
   1 -16  16  -3   3    step 300     sos 531
               * 
   1 -16  13   3   0    step 301     sos 435
       * 
 -15  16  -3   3   0    step 302     sos 499
           * 
 -15  13   3   0   0    step 303     sos 403
   * 
  15  -2   3   0 -15    step 304     sos 463
       * 
  13   2   1   0 -15    step 305     sos 399
                   * 
  -2   2   1 -15  15    step 306     sos 459
   * 
   2   0   1 -15  13    step 307     sos 399
               * 
   2   0 -14  15  -2    step 308     sos 429
                   * 
   0   0 -14  13   2    step 309     sos 369
           * 
   0 -14  14  -1   2    step 310     sos 397
               * 
   0 -14  13   1   1    step 311     sos 367
       * 
 -14  14  -1   1   1    step 312     sos 395
   * 
  14   0  -1   1 -13    step 313     sos 367
                   * 
   1   0  -1 -12  13    step 314     sos 315
               * 
   1   0 -13  12   1    step 315     sos 315
           * 
   1 -13  13  -1   1    step 316     sos 341
       * 
 -12  13   0  -1   1    step 317     sos 315
   * 
  12   1   0  -1 -11    step 318     sos 267
                   * 
   1   1   0 -12  11    step 319     sos 267
               * 
   1   1 -12  12  -1    step 320     sos 291
           * 
   1 -11  12   0  -1    step 321     sos 267
       * 
 -10  11   1   0  -1    step 322     sos 223
   * 
  10   1   1   0 -11    step 323     sos 223
                   * 
  -1   1   1 -11  11    step 324     sos 245
   * 
   1   0   1 -11  10    step 325     sos 223
               * 
   1   0 -10  11  -1    step 326     sos 223
                   * 
   0   0 -10  10   1    step 327     sos 201
           * 
   0 -10  10   0   1    step 328     sos 201
       * 
 -10  10   0   0   1    step 329     sos 201
   * 
  10   0   0   0  -9    step 330     sos 181
                   * 
   1   0   0  -9   9    step 331     sos 163
               * 
   1   0  -9   9   0    step 332     sos 163
           * 
   1  -9   9   0   0    step 333     sos 163
       * 
  -8   9   0   0   0    step 334     sos 145
   * 
   8   1   0   0  -8    step 335     sos 129
                   * 
   0   1   0  -8   8    step 336     sos 129
               * 
   0   1  -8   8   0    step 337     sos 129
           * 
   0  -7   8   0   0    step 338     sos 113
       * 
  -7   7   1   0   0    step 339     sos 99
   * 
   7   0   1   0  -7    step 340     sos 99
                   * 
   0   0   1  -7   7    step 341     sos 99
               * 
   0   0  -6   7   0    step 342     sos 85
           * 
   0  -6   6   1   0    step 343     sos 73
       * 
  -6   6   0   1   0    step 344     sos 73
   * 
   6   0   0   1  -6    step 345     sos 73
                   * 
   0   0   0  -5   6    step 346     sos 61
               * 
   0   0  -5   5   1    step 347     sos 51
           * 
   0  -5   5   0   1    step 348     sos 51
       * 
  -5   5   0   0   1    step 349     sos 51
   * 
   5   0   0   0  -4    step 350     sos 41
                   * 
   1   0   0  -4   4    step 351     sos 33
               * 
   1   0  -4   4   0    step 352     sos 33
           * 
   1  -4   4   0   0    step 353     sos 33
       * 
  -3   4   0   0   0    step 354     sos 25
   * 
   3   1   0   0  -3    step 355     sos 19
                   * 
   0   1   0  -3   3    step 356     sos 19
               * 
   0   1  -3   3   0    step 357     sos 19
           * 
   0  -2   3   0   0    step 358     sos 13
       * 
  -2   2   1   0   0    step 359     sos 9
   * 
   2   0   1   0  -2    step 360     sos 9
                   * 
   0   0   1  -2   2    step 361     sos 9
               * 
   0   0  -1   2   0    step 362     sos 5
           * 
   0  -1   1   1   0    step 363     sos 3
       * 
  -1   1   0   1   0    step 364     sos 3
   * 
   1   0   0   1  -1    step 365     sos 3
                   * 
   0   0   0   0   1    step 366     sos 1
Tue Jun 26 12:07:21 PDT 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

sample:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pentagon  1 1 -3 1 1
Tue Jun 26 18:00:48 PDT 2018
    1    1   -3    1    1  sum 1  sos  13
              * 
    1   -2    3   -2    1    step 1     sos 19
         * 
   -1    2    1   -2    1    step 2     sos 11
    * 
    1    1    1   -2    0    step 3     sos 7
                   * 
    1    1   -1    2   -2    step 4     sos 11
              * 
    1    0    1    1   -2    step 5     sos 7
                        * 
   -1    0    1   -1    2    step 6     sos 7
                   * 
   -1    0    0    1    1    step 7     sos 3
    * 
    1   -1    0    1    0    step 8     sos 3
         * 
    0    1   -1    1    0    step 9     sos 3
              * 
    0    0    1    0    0    step 10     sos 1

 began    1   1  -3   1   1  sum 1  sos  13
Tue Jun 26 18:00:48 PDT 2018
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

==============================================================

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>



using namespace std;

//   g++  -o Pentagon Pentagon.cc  -lm


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if ( argc != 6) cout << "Usage: ./Pentagon  w x y z t    " << endl;
  else {

  int w,x,y,z,t ;

  w = atoi(argv[1]);
  x = atoi(argv[2]);
  y = atoi(argv[3]);
  z = atoi(argv[4]);
  t = atoi(argv[5]);

  int stepbound = 10000;

  system("date");



  int sum = w + x + y + z + t;
  int sos = w * w + x * x + y * y + z * z + t * t ;
  int oldw = w; int oldx = x; int oldy = y; int oldz = z; int oldt = t; int oldsos = sos;
  int goon =  sum > 0;
  int steps = 0;
   int smallsquare;
 cout << setw(5) << w  << setw(5) << x  << setw(5) << y  << setw(5) << z   << setw(5) << t << "  sum " << sum <<  "  sos  " << sos << endl;

  while( goon)
  {
    int w2, x2,y2,z2,t2;
    if( w >= 0) w2 = 1000000000;
    if( w < 0) w2 = w * w + (t + w) * ( t + w) + ( x + w ) * ( x + w ) + y * y + z * z;
     smallsquare = w2;
    int use = 1;

        if( x >= 0) x2 = 1000000000;
       if( x < 0) x2 = x * x + (x + w) * ( x + w) + ( x + y ) * ( x + y ) + z * z + t * t;
    if( smallsquare > x2)
    {
       smallsquare = x2; use = 2;
    }


        if( y >= 0) y2 = 1000000000;
       if( y < 0) y2 = y * y + (y + z) * ( y + z) + ( x + y ) * ( x + y ) + w * w + t * t;
    if( smallsquare > y2)
    {
       smallsquare = y2; use = 3;
    }

        if( z >= 0) z2 = 1000000000;
       if( z < 0) z2 = z * z + (y + z) * ( y + z) + ( z + t ) * ( z + t ) + x * x + w * w;
    if( smallsquare > z2)
    {
       smallsquare = z2; use = 4;
    }

        if( t >= 0) t2 = 1000000000;
       if( t < 0) t2 = t * t + (t + z) * ( t + z) + ( w + t ) * ( w + t ) + x * x + y * y;
    if( smallsquare > t2)
    {
       smallsquare = t2; use = 5;
    }


// w x y z t
//  cout << setw(8) << w2  << setw(8) << x2  << setw(8) << y2  << setw(8) << z2  << setw(8) << t2 << " smallsquare " << smallsquare << endl;
  if( use == 1 ) { x += w; t += w; w *= -1;   cout << "    * " << endl;}
  else if ( use == 2) {w += x; y += x; x *= -1;  cout << "         * " << endl; }
  else if ( use == 3) { x += y; z += y; y *= -1;  cout << "              * " << endl;}
  else if ( use == 4) { y += z; t += z; z *= -1;  cout << "                   * " << endl;}
  else if ( use == 5) { w += t; z += t; t *= -1;  cout << "                        * " << endl;}
//  cout << "  use " << use << endl;
  cout << setw(5) << w  << setw(5) << x  << setw(5) << y  << setw(5) << z   << setw(5) << t <<   "    step " << 1 + steps << "     sos " << smallsquare << endl;

  goon = goon &&  ( w < 0 || x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0  || t < 0  );
   goon = goon && ( abs(w) <= 31622 &&  abs(x) <= 31622 && abs(y) <= 31622 && abs(z) <= 31622 && abs(t) <= 31622    );
    ++steps;
    goon = goon && steps < stepbound;
  } // while goon
if( w < 0 || x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0  || t < 0 ) cout << endl << " did not finish, running with quintuple at step 10000 " << endl ; 
cout << endl << " began " << setw(4) << oldw  << setw(4) << oldx  << setw(4) << oldy  << setw(4) << oldz   << setw(4) << oldt << "  sum " << sum <<  "  sos  " << oldsos << endl;
  system("date");
  } // else argc
  return 0;
}

//        


//   g++  -o Pentagon Pentagon.cc  -lm
```